# EditItemTemplate in silverlight gridview

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am converting some ASP.Net controls to Silverlight. Is there something similar to ASP.Net's `EditItemTemplate` in Silverlight's `DataGrid` or `ListBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit templating in the Silverlight `DataGrid` is performed at the cell level.  If the `DataGrid` default choices are not what you need then you need to use the [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(VS.95).aspx) and define both a `CellTemplate` and a `CellEditingTemplate`.

The `ListBox` does not support the context of an "edit mode" however you can supply an `ItemTemplate` which contains control such as `TextBox` which will allow editing of the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks, i will look at CellEditingTemplate

Answer (score 0):

With the DataGrid you will have control over the Item and the EditingItem. Check this series of DataGrid related posts on my blog:

- [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part I – Introduction](http://smoura.com/index.php/wpf/2009/04/15/introducing-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid/)
- [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part II – Custom Styling](http://smoura.com/index.php/wpf/2009/04/27/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/)
- [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part III – Playing with Columns and Cells](http://smoura.com/index.php/wpf/2009/05/19/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iii-playing-with-datagridcolumns-and-datagridcells/)
- [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part IV: TemplateColumns and Row Grouping](http://smoura.com/index.php/wpf/2009/06/15/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iv-templatecolumns-and-row-grouping/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will review your links shortly

Comment: Many of the principles are the same but these WPF examples use techniques not available in Silverlight

Comment: True... It is not boiler plate code that one can copy / paste. Adapting it to Silverlight should not be a problem though.